# strange behavior in linq to sql to return all rows without filtering

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I write this code:

```
Rep_Regions clsr = new Rep_Regions();
Func<Regions, bool> filter = r => r.RegionID == int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
Regions reg = new Regions();
reg = clsr.FindSingle(filter);
```

and :

```
 public Regions FindSingle(Func<Regions, bool> exp)
    {
        using (RepositoryDataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            return RepositoryDataContext.Regions.Where(exp).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

this is the query that execute in Sql Server:

```
SELECT [t0].[RegionID], [t0].[RegionDescription]
FROM [dbo].[Region] AS [t0]
```

Why the query not filter results and return all rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `Func<Regions, bool> filter` which forces it to use LINQ-to-Objects *after* running an unfiltered query at the server. To use query composition you must use expression-trees, not delegates.

Change it to:

```
int regionId= int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
Expression<Func<Regions, bool>> filter = r => r.RegionID == regionId;
```

Comment: Thank you that is great.what I can use Expression For `Select`?

Comment: @Nima - I don't understand the question in your comment. You can write projections (`Select` etc) in expression trees...